# IPV6 Support over BLE in Android

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ipv6

I am working on BLE mesh for Android and iOS.

We want to work on Addressing scheme for peer to peer communication in Mesh.

Is there any support for IPv6 over BLE (Such as 6LowPAN) in both Android and iOS. Have gone through many documents and not getting it.

Also, is IPSP profile supported over BLE?

It will be helpfull if I can links to some forums.

Comment: https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-technology/topology-options/le-mesh/mesh-tech

Comment: 6LoWPAN is definitely the best approach, but it is not flourished much. Still in development phase.  6LoWPAN is used to directly communicate with end devices, without any smartphone or hub in between. The communication protocol is direct internet, where server will directly talk to end devices.